# How to get the complete response from a telnet command using python?

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib

I am trying to use python 3.10.9 on windows to create a telnet session using [telnetlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html), but I have trouble to read the complete response.

I create a telnet session like

```
session = telnetlib.Telnet(host, port, timeout)
```

and then I write a command like

```
session.write(command + b"\n")
```

and then I wait some really long time (like 5 seconds) before I try to read the response using

```
session.read_some()
```

but I only get half of the response back!

The complete response is e.g.

```
Invalid arguments

Usage: $IMU,START,<SAMPLING_RATE>,<OUTPUT_RATE>
  where SAMPLING_RATE = [1 : 1000] in Hz
        OUTPUT_RATE   = [1 : SAMPLING_RATE] in Hz
```

but all I read is the following:

```
b'\x1b[0GInvalid arguments\r\n\r\nUsage: $IMU,START,<'
```

More than half of the response is missing! How to read the complete response in a **non-blocking** way?

Other strange read methods:

- read_all: blocking
- read_eager: same issue
- read_very_eager: sometimes works, sometimes not. Seems to contain a repetition of the message ...
- read_lazy: does not read anything
- read_very_lazy: does not read anything

I have not the slightest idea what all these different read methods are for. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html) is not helping at all.

But `read_very_eager` seems to work sometimes. But sometimes I get a response like

```
F
FI
FIL
FILT
FILTE
FILTER
```

and so on. But I am reading only once, not adding the output myself!

Maybe there is a more simple-to-use module I can use instead if `telnetlib`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `read_all()`, or any of the other `read_*` options available?

Available functions [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html?highlight=read_some#telnetlib.Telnet.read_some).

Comment: None of the read methods actually seem to work